# Is it possible to integrate yahoo messenger with android apps?

Tags: android, yahoo-messenger

Some of my friends suggest me to use "openymsg", but it always failed when I add its dependency to the build.gradle and sync the gradle. When I put the jar to the "libs" folder, I still can't use it.

Is it even possible to integrate Yahoo Messenger to android apps?
Thank you.

EDIT: Can't use openymsg dependency because of line "repository{ jcenter()}" at build.gradle file. Once I deleted it, openymsg works fine.

Comment: use openymsg library bro

Comment: @Darji Jigar, as I mention above, I already tried that, and it's not working. Is it perhaps I did it in the wrong way?

Comment: @Darji Jigar, I'm sorry, that was because there are line "repository { jcenter }" exists at my build.gradle, after I delete it, openymsg works well. Thank you.

Comment: ok bro i post answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bro used openymsg a library and using below link

http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2011/11/creating-a-simple-yahoo-messenger-auto-response-with-java-and-openymsg-library/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can integrate Yahoo Messenger by add below SDK

Yahoo! Messenger IM SDK - YDN

Comment: It seems rather complicated to use that SDK though :). I'm fairly noob. Do you have some tutorial links about how to use that SDK?